# click( ) or trigger( 'click' ) does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I am using the jquery live method for an anchor element and if I click the anchor then click delegation works as expected. But if I try this on debug console by triggering click event, it never works. Please check the below example

```
<a href="#" id="test">click me</a>

$('#test').live('click',function(){
      alert('live click event');
});
```

If I try to trigger it on console like below. It never works.

```
$('#test').trigger('click');
```

Does anyone know what's causing this problem?

*Note: There are no errors in the Javascript console.*

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Your unclosed href replace: `<a href id="test">click me</a>` with: `<a href="#" id="test">click me</a>` maybe?? See: http://jsfiddle.net/2uLT7/1/

Comment: I haven't tested but my best guess is that the .trigger() method is not bubbling the event.  `live` actually binds the event handler to the document and not the actual element.  I'm a bit perplexed that it isn't working though... I'll test it out and see what's up

Comment: @Curt - I am using 1.6.2 version

Comment: @AndreasAL it is actualy signed href in my own project

Comment: You must have an error somewhere in your code... it works perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/6PDkd/

Comment: *"...it is actualy signed href in my own project"* This makes me think that this is not the actual code you're testing, but it's an example that has been retyped for the question. Is that right? ...with no errors, my first guess would by that you have a typo in the selector used in the console.

Comment: You haven't correctly pared your code down, because the code posted will work. Is there a chance you have a *different* element with the same id attribute in your page? That could cause the symptoms you're describing.

Comment: @meagar code sample that i provide is working version already but i wanted to know that what can cause this problem. Id conflict was one of them but i checked it and i see that it is unique.

Comment: FWIW, the concept of a `live` handler on an id is contradictory. You should only ever have one and only one id on a page, and if that's the case, `live` is unnecessary. If you know what the element is and it appears only once, you can apply a standard click handler to it on page load or when it's inserted.

Comment: You are right. I also using live with class selector. I understand that everything looks ok. I will post it if i can find reason of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is fine, so one of the following might be the cause of the problem:

1. As mentioned in a comment before, you might have another tag with the same id (I know this is not the case, but if other people will read this, we might be able to help them by enlisting all imaginable causes of the problem)
2. You might have an event on your page which deletes the tag, so when you try to query it in your console the tag doesn't exist any more, in this case you try to get a nonexistent object
3. The given tag might be created only on a certain event and maybe when you try to reach the tag it doesn't exist yet, because the event which triggers it was not triggered yet
4. You might have a naming issue

If none of the above matches your case, you should try to run any other jquery command. If other jquery commands fail too then the source of the problem might not be where you are looking for it.

If none of the ideas above help you, you might consider giving us more details about the structure (markup) and functionality of your system. Maybe someone is able to help you.